# can't cast to integer

Tags: java, xml-rpc

I am writing a java program where I want to simulate a client-server relationship with remote procedure calls using xmlrpc.

However when I try to remotely call the method I get this error message:

'JavaClient: XML-RPC Consumer Fault #java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer'

This is the method on the client side that is producing the error:

```
public String getHashsize() {

      // Execute the remote call, using the handler
         try
     {
         argHashsize = new Vector(); //see next method for comments
         argHashsize.addElement(serverURL);

         // make the call
         String callit = ("GetSize.sendHashSize");
         sizeHash =  (Integer)client.execute(callit, argHashsize );
     }
         // Use XmlRpcException errors
         catch (XmlRpcException exception) {
             System.err.println("JavaClient: XML-RPC Consumer Fault #" +
                                Integer.toString(exception.code) + ": " +
                                exception.getCause() + "" + exception.toString());
         } catch (Exception exception) {
             System.err.println("JavaClient: XML-RPC Consumer Fault #" + exception.toString());
         }
      String StrsizeHash = Integer.toString(sizeHash); // Cast sizeHash to String
     return StrsizeHash;
     }
```

This is the method that I am attempting to call:

```
public String sendHashSize(String getCaller) {
        // send back info to Message Broker
        sendbackserverdata = "number of staff: " + theHashtable.noStaff()
                + "  Caller: " + getCaller
                + "  Port: " + getServerPort()
                + "  " + getSendtime();
        //Store server info in Hashtable persist - could be a database
    /*persist.put("" + theHashtable.noStaff(),"" + sendbackserverdata);
         sendServerData = sendbackserverdata;
         stats.StoreinStatsHashtable("" + theHashtable.noStaff(), sendbackserverdata);*/
        return sendbackserverdata; // return to Consumer
    }
```

Comment: Which one line *throws* the exception?

Answer (score 5):

Your `sendHashSize` method returns a `String`. It's not even the string representation of an integer - it's a string starting with "number of staff:".

I'm not surprised that it failed with an exception - it's just surprising that you expected it to work. Which integer would you have expected as a result?

Either change `sendHashSize` to return an `int`/`Integer` (perhaps `theHashtable.noStaff()`?), or avoid trying to cast it to an `Integer` on the calling side.

Additionally, this code is misleading:

```
catch (Exception exception) {
    System.err.println("JavaClient: XML-RPC Consumer Fault #" + exception.toString());
}
```

It's *not* an "XML-RPC Consumer Fault" - you've already caught those in the previous line. You've got an exception because you're trying to cast a `String` to an `Integer`... which is nothing to do with the XML-RPC layer.

Comment: @ReverendGonzo: Yes, I know it's the method he's trying to call. But that's going to return a string, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
sizeHash =  (Integer)client.execute(callit, argHashsize );
```

try:

```
sizeHash =  Integer.valueOf(client.execute(callit, argHashsize ));
```

Of course that you have to make sure that a *real* integer is sent otherwise you'll get an exception for trying to convert a non-integer string to an integer (NumberFormatException).

**Preferred approach**:

The method `sendHashSize()` should return an int/Integer - and then you don't have to cast to Integer or use Integer.valueOf()

Comment: Have you seen the string which is going to be sent back? It's really not an integer at all...

Comment: @JonSkeet patience my dear :) I didn't finish writing

Comment: There's no indication that it's really meant to be a string representation of an integer... if the OP wants to return an integer, he should just do so.

Comment: Your edit still won't work at all. How will Integer return the valueOf "Port:... etc.."?

Comment: @JonSkeet there's no indication of what's supposed to be returned at all - both of us just assume... I agree with your comment - an integer should be returned otherwise he won't be able to use it... as an integer :)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I didn't understand your comment - can you please explain ?

Comment: @alfasin: No, my point is that if the OP wants to return an integer, he should have a method with a return type of `Integer` so that the cast *will* work. There's no need to convert it to a string and back.

Comment: @JonSkeet I agree - that's the *right* way to do it, but of course he can also return a String that will be parsed if he wants to. I wouldn't recommend on doing it this way - but it's possible.

Comment: If you "wouldn't recommend on doing it this way" then I'm not sure why you've added an answer which *does* suggest doing it that way, with no mention of any alternative. Just seems odd to me.

Answer (score 0):

The sendHashSize() method should have the following code instead:

```
public int sendHashSize(String getCaller)
   {
    // return to Consumer
    return theHashtable.noStaff();
   }
```